# Defining Inertia Stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topos and $F: \zeta \rightarrow X$ a stack on $X$. Now in the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411337v2.pdf  *( Definitions 2.1.1.5 and 2.1.1.1)* of Lieblich, he describes the inertia stack associated to the given stack $\zeta$ to be the stack corresponding to the sheaf given by the following assignment:

$$(f:S \rightarrow \zeta) \longrightarrow Autf $$
where $S$ ranges over all
sheaves on (=objects of) $X$.

Now, what I don't understand is that, for a morphism $f \rightarrow g$ what is the corresponding map $Autf \rightarrow Autg$? I can't figure out how given an automorphism of $f$ and just any morphism from $f\rightarrow g$, I can get an automorphism of $g$!
This is of course not possible in general. However, I guess somehow some properties of stack might be used to see this.

Can someone please help me understand this ?

Thanks!

Comment: It is said explicitly in paragraph 2 of 2.1 that "stack" in that paper means "stack in groupoids" (with extensions beyond that left to the interested reader), so morphisms $f \rightarrow g$ are isomorphisms...

Comment: Here's a way to see it: an automorphism of $f$ is a natural transformation $\alpha\colon f\rightarrow f$ as functors $S\to \mathscr{S}$. If you have a map $g\to f$, that means that you have a (2-)commutative diagram $S'\to S\to \mathscr{S}$, where the composite is (isomorphic to) $g$. To obtain the automorphism induced on the object $g$, just take the induced natural transformation on the composite $S'\to S\to \mathscr{S}$ (considering all these as categories).